# why does my pygame load into a blank screen on mac?

Tags: python, macos, pygame

For some reason when i run the code in netbeans i only get a blank screen

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# define colours
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 50))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Update
all_sprites.update()

    # Draw / render
screen.fill(BLACK)
all_sprites.draw(screen)
# *after* drawing everything, flip the display
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

please help me. when i run the code in netbeans it works but the screen where the game should be is blank, when i close the screen there is a frame of it in colour before it closes the window. I'm using OSX sierra

Comment: Indent the seven lines below `# Update`.

Answer (score 1):

The sprites update and rendering calls are not being made in your while loop.

As pointed out in the comments, you need to indent the seven lines below `# Update`.  Try this:

```
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Update
    all_sprites.update()

    # Draw / render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```